# Builtin read no asigna valor a una variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

Debo de realizar estos pasos haciendo scripting en Linux:

> Debe leer dos números por teclado e indicar
> si son iguales o en caso contrario indicar el mayor.

Eso es lo que he escrito, pero no funciona:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "mensaje"
num1
read -p "mensaje"
num2
if [ $num1 -eq $num2 ]
then
        echo $num1 es igual que $num2
else
        if [ $num1 -gt $num2 ]
        then
                echo $num1 es mayor que $num2
        else
                echo $num2 es mayor que $num1
        fi
fi
```

Adjunto el fallo en una imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya lo he cambiado

Comment: debes poner el código tal cuál está en el script. Como lo has puesto no se distingue como has codificado cada instrucción.

Comment: num1 y num2 ponlos en  la misma linea del read

Answer (score 2):

La variable que va a contener el `read` debe ir en la misma linea. En tu caso  has puesto la variable en la siguiente y  por lo  tanto, el `bash`ejecutará esa linea como una instrucción. `num1 orden no  encontrada`.

Pon las variables en la misma linea:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "mensaje " num1
read -p "mensaje " num2
if [ $num1 -eq $num2 ]
then
 echo $num1 es igual que $num2
else 
   if [ $num1 -gt $num2 ] 
   then 
      echo $num1 es mayor que $num2 
   else 
      echo $num2 es mayor que $num1 
   fi 
fi
```

NOTA: Olvidé mencionar que cuando no le pones una  variable al `read` el resultado lo pone en la variable especial $REPLY

Comment: Ya funciona, eres un grande. Muchas gracias

Comment: Acepta la respuesta para que no quede sin responder

Answer (score 0):

Según la ayuda de bash sobre el builtin `read`:

```
$ bash -c "help read"
read: read (...)[name ...]
(...)
Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD
if the -u option is supplied.  The line is split into fields as with word 
splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME
(...)
```

Es decir, lee de la entrada estandar y luego asigna a, según la separación, la palabra a la variable NAME, y así sucesivamente.

En otras palabras, debes de borrar el salto de línea para que todo se use según lo establecido por `bash`.

Tu problema sucede porque dejas que `read` trunque su trabajo y abajo le indicas a bash que utilice un nombre desconocido.